# What is differences between us8216392 and us7445677?

Tags: prior-art, novelty, us8216392, us7445677

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there an infringement between this patent and lufthansa us8216392 patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/is-there-an-infringement-between-this-patent-and-lufthansa-us8216392-patent)

[us8216392](http://www.google.com/patents/US8216392) patent produced "cyclean" you can google for images and [us7445677](http://www.google.com/patents/US7445677) drawings are very close, and also claims are very close